# Мультиязычный сайт

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать мультиязычный сайт?
И работало через MySQL.
Например человек в админке вводит информацию на русском языке нажимает "Сохранить" и скрипт сразу переводит на английский язык и сохраняет в базу и английский и русский текст.

Comment: Что именно интересует? 
структура бд?
или чем переводить?

т.к давать готовый код на весь мультиязычный сайт глупо

Comment: Как переводить.

Comment: Drupal чем не устраивает?

Comment: Юзай Google API.

Answer (score 2):

Перевести - это одно, а сделать литературный перевод программа врядли сможет. Ну, через десять лет, я думаю это и будет возможно, но не сегодня. Убогий перевод только оттолкнет пользователя, так что не заморачивайся.

Comment: Полностью согласен! Быдло перевод никому не нужен!

Answer (score 1):

В гугле платно, там по моему за 1 миллион символов 1$, если не ошибаюсь. Советую использовать: **Microsoft® Translator Webmaster Offerings**
 Не давно начал работать над переводчиком для одного форума, и тоже искал сайты для удобного перевода строк, и [нашел](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/web/)

очень удобно, страница документации: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd576287.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Правильно — **никак**.

Answer (score 0):

API гугл транслейтера.
Хотя оно вроде в 11 году было закрыто. Не знаю, открыли ли. Скачайте плагин для вордпреса "переводчик" и посмотрите, через что переводит он. Или костыли на транслейтер делайте.